# OpenCL: Basic example not working. clSetKernelArg -38 Error

Tags: opencl

I am attempting a very simple OpenCL example. I have developed the following code below. It compiles a simple kernel, and then I create a simple float* buffer and set it to a cl::Buffer. However, when I attempt to call the kernel.setArg() function, it crashes, with an error -38. This error states that my cl::Buffer is invalid. I have no idea why this is happening:

```
#define CL_HPP_ENABLE_EXCEPTIONS
#define CL_HPP_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION 200
#include <CL/cl2.hpp>

#define MULTI_LINE_STRING(ARG) #ARG

namespace op
{
    const char *resizeAndMergeKernel = MULTI_LINE_STRING(
        __kernel void testKernel(__global float* image)
        {
        }
    );
}

void testCL(){
    cl::Device device;
    cl::Context context;
    cl::CommandQueue queue;
    int deviceId = 0;

    // Load Device
    std::vector<cl::Platform> platforms;
    std::vector<cl::Device> devices;
    std::string deviceName;
    cl_uint i, type;
    cl::Platform::get(&platforms);
    type = platforms[0].getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, &devices);
    if( type == CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        // Get only relavent device
        cl::Context allContext(devices);
        std::vector<cl::Device> gpuDevices;
        gpuDevices = allContext.getInfo<CL_CONTEXT_DEVICES>();
        bool deviceFound = false;
        for(int i=0; i<gpuDevices.size(); i++){
            if(i == deviceId){
                device = gpuDevices[i];
                context = cl::Context(device);
                queue = cl::CommandQueue(context, device, CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE);
                deviceFound = true;
                cout << "Made new GPU Instance: " << deviceId << endl;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!deviceFound)
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("Error: Invalid GPU ID");
        }
    }

    // Create Kernel
    cl::Program program = cl::Program(context, op::resizeAndMergeKernel, true);
    cl::Kernel kernel = cl::Kernel(program, "testKernel");

    // Simple Buffer
    cl_int err;
    float* test = new float[3*224*224];
    cl::Buffer x = cl::Buffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, sizeof(float) * 3 * 224 * 224, (void*)test, &err);
    cout << err << endl;

    kernel.setArg(0,x); // CRASHES WITH cl::Error -38
}
```

As you can see the last line kernel.setArg(0,x) crashes with error -38.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a "crash", it's an error code. OpenCL error -38 is CL_INVALID_MEM_OBJECT. It means the cl_mem_obj is not valid. It is because you are passing a cl::Buffer object to setArg, but you need to instead pass the cl_mem handle which represents that buffer. The cl::Buffer operator() method returns that. So use `kernel.setArg(0,x())`. Note the `()` are the added part (yes, it's subtle).

Comment: yes and also the fact that i created a cl::Program without passing in the context